# Need CXF Server side configuration to validate different client webService calls signed with different X509 certs

Tags: cxf, x509

I have a scenario where i have to configure CXF at server side to intercept an inbound WebService call which I have to decrypt and validate the signature of the message. It is a multi client having all messages signed and encrypted using X509 cert and a single web service on server side that process all these client calls. All these different clients calling my WebService with different X509 certificates. I am looking here for CXF configuration on my server which can validate the signature based on public key of respective client. I already have a solution for a single client and Server only CXF configuration where i configure signature properties that include merlin defining client key store location. I am looking for CXF server side configuration to validate signature of these (multi) client webservice calls that are having the input message signed with different X509 cert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CXF libraries i.e the Merlin.java implementation to validate the request for the signature or encryption or the username token or issue token etc.

org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin